# Homebrew: Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc@6' on Mac10.13.6

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm, gcc6

I can't install ruby 3.0.0 through my powershell, when I try `rvm install 3.0.0` I receive a beautiful error:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc@6',
please read /Users/ben/.rvm/log/1673079096_ruby-3.0.0/package_install_gcc@6.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I feel like I've tried everything to resolve this problem but without success.

-This is my gcc version:

`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

-homebrew version:

`Homebrew 3.6.17-66-g974984d Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 0149ce7e63e; last commit 2023-01-07)`

-rvm version:

`rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]`

-ruby version:

`ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]`

-which ruby:

`/usr/bin/ruby`

And when I run `rvm install 3.0.0` this is what I receive:

```
Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.
Usage: brew search, -S [options] text|/regex/ [...]

Perform a substring search of cask tokens and formula names for text. If
text is flanked by slashes, it is interpreted as a regular expression. The
search for text is extended online to homebrew/core and homebrew/cask.

      --formula, --formulae        Search online and locally for formulae.
      --cask, --casks              Search online and locally for casks.
      --desc                       Search for formulae with a description
                                   matching text and casks with a name or
                                   description matching text.
      --eval-all                   Evaluate all available formulae and casks,
                                   whether installed or not, to search their
                                   descriptions. Implied if HOMEBREW_EVAL_ALL is
                                   set.
      --pull-request               Search for GitHub pull requests containing
                                   text.
      --open                       Search for only open GitHub pull requests.
      --closed                     Search for only closed GitHub pull requests.
      --repology                   Search for text in the given database.
      --macports                   Search for text in the given database.
      --fink                       Search for text in the given database.
      --opensuse                   Search for text in the given database.
      --fedora                     Search for text in the given database.
      --archlinux                  Search for text in the given database.
      --debian                     Search for text in the given database.
      --ubuntu                     Search for text in the given database.
  -d, --debug                      Display any debugging information.
  -q, --quiet                      Make some output more quiet.
  -v, --verbose                    Make some output more verbose.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.

Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.
Installing requirements for osx_brew.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: gcc@6........There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc@6',
please read /Users/benoitlardinois/.rvm/log/1673081014_ruby-3.0.0/package_install_gcc@6.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So, if I run `brew install gcc@6`, I receive:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from MacHomebrew on Twitter.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.

Warning: gcc@6 has been deprecated because it is deprecated upstream!
==> Fetching dependencies for gcc@6: isl, mpfr and libmpc
==> Fetching isl
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/03cf8088210822aa2c1ab544ed
Already downloaded: /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/195208ba31cadc265ea97bb8aad4e78caab1200daf4d855e6c839b5f987f92db--configure-big_sur.diff
==> Downloading https://libisl.sourceforge.io/isl-0.25.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/dce6d1ed4d25c923a4ad350c4b9cdf03406f649cd55be8c385814703502b5c81--isl-0.25.tar.xz
==> Fetching mpfr
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-4.2.0.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2b7a1efec00f58b200d550146d18563516f005674020aa39ca2cd6666cb1d215--mpfr-4.2.0.tar.xz
==> Fetching libmpc
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc/mpc-1.3.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/22a255b07a458ea7bd9717c0d1509282a69135dd842aa6b64144820c50bfd208--mpc-1.3.1.tar.gz
==> Fetching gcc@6
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.5.0/gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0a7c1b4768113746153c6e06f4ea6b2abf2d8ba48a68bf28f7c686b70117540e--gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz
==> Installing dependencies for gcc@6: isl, mpfr and libmpc
==> Installing gcc@6 dependency: isl
==> Patching
==> Applying configure-big_sur.diff
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 13866 (offset 5133 lines).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/isl/0.25 --with-gmp=system --with-gmp-prefix=/usr/local/op
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/benoitlardinois/Library/Logs/Homebrew/isl/02.make:
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:933:33: note: candidate function has been explicitly made unavailable
    constexpr value_type const& value() const&
                                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:951:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'optional<...>' to 'optional<...>' for object argument
    constexpr value_type&& value() &&
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:960:34: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'optional<...>' to 'const optional<...>' for object argument
    constexpr value_type const&& value() const&&
                                 ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [isl_test_cpp17.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Error: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from MacHomebrew on Twitter.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
```

I'm in despair, I don't know what I'm supposed  to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is clearly stating that macOS 10.13 is too old, so the best thing is to upgrade the OS - there were several failed attempts to build Ruby 3.0 - see https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5055

Also, GCC below version 10 are deprecated - see homebrew issue https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/110163

Though, you can first try switching from rvm to rbenv - seems like someone get it done with rbenv on High Sierra - https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5012#issuecomment-811858777

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Well, I use an old iMac(2011) and I can't run my macOS over High Sierra 10.13. So, I ended up to use ruby 2.7.2 and rails 6.1.1.